# Javascript while command failed

Tags: javascript

I'm really new to JavaScript, so I tried to make a super simple until command, but it didn't work.

```js
var sunSize = sunSize;
while(sunSize<300) {sunSize+1};
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Java != JS. Which are you using, what are you trying to achieve here and what didn't work specifically? Seems like you could just set `sunSize = 300` instead of using a loop.

Comment: You're missing `=` - `sunSize+=1`

Comment: `sunSize+1` does nothing, you need `sunSize++;` or `sunSize += 1;` or `sunSize = sunSize + 1`. You also want something like `var SunSize = 1;` at the start.

Comment: I kinda want the sunsize to increase over a small period of time

Comment: Is this Java or JavaScript? It looks like the latter but you should be clear. And can you explain why you're trying to do it this way? The trivial solution has already been mentioned but there's really no reason to do this with a loop in the first place.

Comment: first lesson about javascript : it is not  java

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/3t8eqcpn/ (you should probably start simpler; JS is primarily event based, this is not a good direction for a beginner)

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if one of them helped you; this tells others that the answer is correct and helps others find the correct answer more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 mistakes:

1. You initialize `sunSize` incorrectly. It needs to be set to some value; if you just do `sunSize = sunSize` it will result in it being undefined.
2. Instead of `sunzize+1`, you need to do `sunSize = sunSize + 1` or `sunSize += 1` or `sunSize++`. This will increase `sunSize` by 1 which is what I assume you were trying to do.
3. A `while` loop doesn't require a semicolon at the end, but a declaration does. Therefore I just moved the semicolon inside the `while` loop.

Below is working Javascript code:

```js
var sunSize = 1;
while(sunSize<300) {sunSize++;}
console.log(sunSize);
// Logs 300
```

Comment: `while ( ++sunSize < 300 ) {}`

Comment: @MisterJojo That would be better, but as the OP is a beginner I figured I wouldn't introduce too many new concepts.

Answer (score 0):

so for starters you are trying to initialize sunSize to sunSize, which you can't do because it doesn't exist yet.  So first initialize it to a number, say 0 or whatever.  Also, try not to use the 'var' keyword, use 'let' (if the variable is going to be changed) or 'const' (if the variable is not going to change). In this case you're updating the variable inside your loop so use 'let' like this:

```
let sunSize = 0;
```

Second, 'sunSize+1' is not proper syntax; what you want is either +=1, or ++:

```
while (sunSize < 300) { sunSize++; }
```

Hope this was helpful!  Welcome to javascript!

Comment: This answer is wrong. The code will end with `sunSize == 300` because the loop will go one more time when `sunSize == 299`.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 You're right, I must have been typing faster than my brain was thinking.  I'll edit it.